# Error when using argv in Python 3, for exercise 14 in Learning Python the Hard way. Found no answer yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, valueerror, argv

I am a beginner using Python 3. I am running all my code in Jupyer Notebook. I am trying to work through exercise 14 from "Learn Python the Hard Way". Yet, I am having troubles every time I use "argv" in each exercise. It seems like the coding used in the book is not doing the same than when I run the code myself in Jupyter Notebook. I share coding exercise below:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))
print ("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print ("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)
likes = input(prompt)

print ("Where do you live %s" % user_name)
lives = input(prompt)

print ("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)

print ("""
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""") % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Here is the "What you should see" example from the book:

```
$ python ex14.py zed
Hi zed, I'm the ex14.py script.
I'd like to ask you a few questions. Do you like me zed?
> Yes
Where do you live zed?
> San Francisco
What kind of computer do you have? > Tandy 1000
Alright, so you said 'Yes' about liking me.
You live in 'San Francisco'. Not sure where that is. And you have a 'Tandy 1000' computer. Nice.
```

However, this is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6j/wrrp3rp57jgc9fvl_2sz5mcm0000gn/T/ipykernel_8070/610999341.py in <module>
      1 from sys import argv
      2 
----> 3 script, user_name = argv
      4 prompt = '> '
      5 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here some helpful additional information to solve the problem I am running into:

When I code:

```
 import sys

print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

I get:

"Number of arguments: 3 arguments.

Argument List: ['/Users/xxxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/Users/xxxx/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-d826df3e-536b-4c4f-bcb6-ee3fbcb3158c.json']"

Finally, if I try to add one more variable in argv, then the previous error goes away, but the code is still not doing what the book is showing, plus I get a new error. This is what I get instead.

Output from Jupyter Notebook:

```
Hi -f, I'm the /Users/xxxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py script.
I'd like to ask you a few questions.
Do you like me -f?
> No
Where do you live -f?
> In the USA
What kind of computer do you have?
> MacOS

Alright, so you said %r about liking me. You live in %r. Not sure where that is. And you have a %r computer. Nice."

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6j/wrrp3rp57jgc9fvl_2sz5mcm0000gn/T/ipykernel_8070/2115822038.py in <module>
     11 print ("What kind of computer do you have?")
     12 computer = input(prompt)
---> 13 print ("""
     14 Alright, so you said %r about liking me. You live in %r. Not sure where that is. And you have a %r computer. Nice.
     15 """) % (likes, lives, computer)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

So, it seems that argv is already defined by Python. Also, it seems that I cannot change the variables or command-lines from argv. A clue I have is that for some reason I cannot run this code on Jupyter Notebook. It seems that the author of the book  What is the problem I am running into and how can I solve it to actually do what this exercise intend?

Thank you.

Comment: The `print` at the end is failing because you're using an obsolete book based on Python 2.x.  You could fix it by putting another set of parentheses around the entire parameter to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a python script, the passed arguments are stored in the  `sys.argv` list. To get the same in a jupyter notebook, you need to pass them via the `%%python` stanza:

```
%%python - --username zed --other parameters

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
```

This will yield `['-', '--username', 'zed', '--other', 'parameters']`, which you can then parse to your liking.

### Edit

Jupyter notebooks are designed for interaction rather than script execution. If you are set on using jupyter *and* passing parameters to your script, you have two options:

- very crude but effective: overwrite sys.argv with the arguments you would have passed:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['ex14', 'zed']
```

and then continue as if you were running a script.

- export a notebook snippet into a file using the `%%file` magic:

```
%%file ex14.py
import sys
script, user_name = sys.argv
print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))
```

and then run it with:

```
%%!python ex14.py zed
```

Comment: This does not work either. It will print those parameters as you said but it does not work for the exercise I am trying to do. I will get a new error once I add that line of code which says: `CalledProcessError: Command 'b'\nimport sys\n\nif __name__ == \'__main__\':\n    print(sys.argv)\n\nscript, first, second = argv\n    \nprint ("The script is called:", script)\nprint ("Your first variable is :", first)\nprint ("Your second variable is :", second)\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: I edited the response to address the issue explicitly. The bottom line is that jupyter notebook is meant to be interactive so you'll have to resort to workarounds to get the scripting functionality you are learning about. I provided you with two options there but I'm sure there are other workarounds you can conjure. Personally, I'd stay away from parsing argv altogether when using jupyter notebooks.